# Target Android Email Clients?

Tags: android, css, email, html-email

Is there a way to target android email clients only with css?

As they do not respond to media queries I need to do some special styling for these clients only.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific way to target just Android. The problem is, Android is the OS, not the email client, the user might be using any of a number of different email clients. A better approach would be to decide which email clients you want to support on Android and then look for ways to target them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we associate Android email with Gmail. Gmail supports media queries except on Gmail Android with Non Gmail Accounts. It would be awesome if every email reader provided us with a unique identifier to target that type of client.

Until then, maybe this will give you better clarification.

- https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6266-gmail-app-media-query-support
- https://emails.hteumeuleu.com/trying-to-make-sense-of-gmail-css-support-after-the-2016-update-53c15151063a

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<style>
div > u + .body .gmail{
    display:block !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="body" >
  <div class="gmail" style="display:none;">
    THIS IS GMAIL ON ANDROID
  </div>
</body></html>
```

See: http://freshinbox.com/blog/targeting-new-gmail-css/